# Make a cell's background transparent, without also making the text transparent

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I want to have a transparent background, but I can't seem to get that without making the text in the cells transparent as well. Here is what I have.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSString *labelString = @"Hello";

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
cell.alpha 0.2f;

cell.textLabel.textcolor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.text = labelString;
```

I have tried several other things such as setting the contentView's background color and alpha, as well as the backgroundView's color and alpha, nothing seems to work.

---

Comment: Please show us how you create the cell and and set the background for the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing this code in the `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` solved the issue.

```
UIView *backView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
```

Comment: whats the point making `alpha= 0.2f` when the color is alredy `clearColor`

Comment: I would suggest you do this directly in your UITableViewCell subclass or if using UITableViewCell directly then in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because if you do this in willDisplayCell, it's going to create that background view for each cell, each and every time a cell comes onto the screen (think of the scrolling) - not good at all for performance.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of setting the cell.alpha,

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

You may also need to set the table view background.